pandas concat two dataframes with same column names returning InvalidIndexError
I have two Dataframes with same column names and when I try to concat them based on one column as index I am getting an InvalidIndexError intermittently and I am not able to figure out why.
Here is the data representation
adf:



A
B
C




abcd
AB
1.0


a
AC
1.1


b
AD
1.1


c
AE
2.0



bdf



A
B
C




abcd
AB
1.1


a
AC
1.1


b
AX
1.2


c
AF
2.0



Column A doesn't change in both dfs but column B, C may/may not have changes.My final goal is to have a df to compare what changed and what hasn't.
Below code snipped is what I have used:
df_all = pd.concat([adf.set_index('A'), bdf.set_index('A')], axis='columns', keys=['cur', 'new'])
When this works, It returns data in this format
df_all -

Ignore 1.0 to 1 and 2.0 to 2 as I posted image from Excel
However intermittently it returns InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects error with some slight change in data (but not columns).
What could be causing this?
Also, Any other suggestions to bring the data in the above format is appreciated.

not sure how the table got messed up, can someone suggest an edit?

The error occurs when you have a duplicated 'A', can you please update your example to demonstrate what should be done in such case?

This error occurs when you have a duplicate in the index (here in your column A).
Here is an example that reproduces the error:
adf = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['abcd', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
                    'B': ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE'],
                    'C': [1.0, 1.1, 1.1, 2.0]})
bdf = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['abcd', 'a', 'b', 'b'],
                    'B': ['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE'],
                    'C': [1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.0]})
pd.concat([adf.set_index('A'), bdf.set_index('A')], axis='columns', 
keys=['cur', 'new'])
# InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

You can either remove the duplicates:
dfs = [adf, bdf]
out = pd.concat([x.drop_duplicates('A').set_index('A') for x in dfs],
                axis='columns', keys=['cur', 'new'])

Output:
     cur       new     
       B    C    B    C
A                      
abcd  AB  1.0   AB  1.1
a     AC  1.1   AC  1.1
b     AD  1.1   AD  1.1
c     AE  2.0  NaN  NaN

Or de-duplicate with groupby.cumcount with a second level:
dfs = [adf, bdf]
out = pd.concat([x.set_index(['A', x.groupby('A').cumcount()]) for x in dfs],
                axis='columns', keys=['cur', 'new']).sort_index()

Output:
        cur       new     
          B    C    B    C
A                         
a    0   AC  1.1   AC  1.1
abcd 0   AB  1.0   AB  1.1
b    0   AD  1.1   AD  1.1
     1  NaN  NaN   AE  2.0  # the second "b" row was deduplicated
c    0   AE  2.0  NaN  NaN

A final option, if you want the combinations of row when they are duplicated would be to merge:
adf.merge(bdf, on='A', suffixes=('_cur', '_new')).set_index('A')

Output:
     B_cur  C_cur B_new  C_new
A                             
abcd    AB    1.0    AB    1.1
a       AC    1.1    AC    1.1
b       AD    1.1    AD    1.1
b       AD    1.1    AE    2.0

